# How can I block IP addresses on Web Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, iis-7.5, windows

I'm running Windows Web Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5, I need to secure one site to be used internally only from 10.0.0.0/8. IIS is running normally now. My current sites are bound to the internal IP address and serving content to the Internet.

I can't find the IPv4 IP and Domain Restrictions module. This module is allegedly named IpRestrictionModule, but I don't see it in my modules list either. All Windows critical updates are installed.

All of the posts I find for IIS 7 (or 7.5?) mention this module, and I don't have it. How can I install/setup this module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps reference this article [IP and Domain Restrictions](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity) remembering you may need to install **IP and Domain Restrictions** as referenced in the **Setup** section of that page.

Comment: That was it. I opened Server Manager --> Roles --> Web Server (IIS) --> Add Role Services. The wizard (2 steps) allowed me to Select, under Security, IP and Domain Restrictions.

Comment: Thank you! succesfully blocked a bot via ip address who was attacking my server with this ip and domain restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889.aspx) link ?   (would have added as a comment, but URLs don't appear as links)